# Generated PDF throws "...This is currently disalowed by your system administrator."

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, oraclereports

In a PDF file generated by Oracle Reports, pressing on a drill-down link (something like **/reports/rwservlet?report=test.rep&destype=cache&desformat=pdf**), I receive the following error message:

```
This file is set to be launched by this PDF file. This is currently disalowed by your system administrator.
```

Does anyone encounter a problem like this? Maybe in another context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the url of your webserver need to be a "trusted location" see
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Professional/WS8084ADD0-83CB-43fe-B3CC-0D9AF9224C8C.w.html#WS143C83B9-D6A8-49bd-90A7-26ECEB7B0D4A.w

hth

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an oracle-specific security issue.  Where exactly is the message coming from?  JS in the PDF, or something returned from the link?

Comment: It is from the pdf. I don't think it is something specific from Oracle.